# Apache blocking (not simply rewriting or redirecting) standard http request

Tags: django, apache, http, https

I have a site with a particular path that I am attempting to use as a download repository for another piece of software.  Because this site is distributed to be used by third parties I cannot rely on the certificate of this site to be legit (third parties can install their own certs) I need to access this repository via http and not https or my installing software will balk and not install the files because it doesn't trust the site.  I have currently been forcing all http requests to https using Apaches RewriteEngine.  I updated the configuration of that with the following:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !.*/path/to/repo/.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

<VirtualHost>

</VirtualHost _default_:*>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .*/path/to/repo/.* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# More configuration down here.
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I attempt to access http://www.example.net/path/to/repo/ it simply gives me a not found error immediately

I dug further into this and removed the rewrite from http to https completely and found that I could not access any of the pages of my site at all if I attempted to use standard http

This is a Django website so I looked through my settings file to see if there was something in there that would prevent it from accepting http and found nothing obvious.  Is there another setting somewhere I should check (perhaps in apache's config) to see if standard http has been disabled?

Comment: So I am discovering that this seems to be a configuration problem, where port 80 is only doing the redirect to https and nothing more when something comes in not matching that redirect regex it no longer hits a valid host because all of that setup is done in the VirtualHost that follows.  I attempted to move the https redirect code into the lower and then remove the explicit :80 altogether and now I get:  'Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as I suspected in my comment above.  Because there was an explicit VirtualHost being defined for port 80 only, any thing that made it though the redirect filter (which had previously been filtering everything) was then falling on deaf ears because there was not a host set up to listen to these requests.

In order to fix this I had to define a process to accept these connections.

Here is a more full version of the code including what I did to fix it:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
# redirecting all but repo requests to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !.*/path/to/repo/.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/repo-host.access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess repo-host user=admin group=repo-host processes=2 threads=2 maximum-requests=1500 inactivity-timeout=60 deadlock-timeout=45
WSGIProcessGroup repo-host
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/appliance.wsgi
WSGIPassAuthorization on

SSLEngine off
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
# redirecting https requests to the repo back to http
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .*/path/to/repo/.* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl-host.access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess ssl-host user=admin group=ssl-host processes=5 threads=5 maximum-requests=1500 inactivity-timeout=60 deadlock-timeout=45
WSGIProcessGroup ssl-host
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/appliance.wsgi
WSGIPassAuthorization on

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/ssl-cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/ssl-cert.key

</VirtualHost>
```

If there is a better way to solve this, please comment below or submit your own answer to let me know.  Thanks